# Начальный этап написания слайдера картинок

Tags: jquery

Пытаюсь написать слайдер картинок. Вот, что у меня пока [получилось](http://vinnie95.22web.net/slide/1.html). Прокомментируйте, пожалуйста.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
    var slide = 500;
    var pos = 1;
    $('#left').click(function () {
        slide2 = slide * pos;
        $('ul').animate({
            marginLeft: '-' + slide2 + 'px'
        }, 700);
        if (pos < ($('img').length) - 1) pos += 1;
        else pos = 1;
    })
})
</script>
```

и

```
<style>
#main {
    border: 1px solid 0px;
    height: 320px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 500px;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 10000px;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

</style>
```

и

```
<div id="main">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="01.jpg"/></li>
        <li><img src="02.jpg"/></li>
        <li><img src="03.jpg"/></li>
        <li><img src="04.jpg"/></li>
        <li><img src="05.jpg"/></li>
    </ul>
    <div style="margin-top:290px">
        <button id="left"></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Стрелки должны быть строго в другую сторону. По аналогии со скроллом. Просто потому что так все привыкли: указывается направление смещения относительно ленты, а не направление смещения ленты относительно монитора.
В остальном - довольно симпатично.

Кстати, как решена проблема с картинками ДРУГИХ пропорций?

Comment: Спасибо! щу думаю, как вторую стрелку замутить)

Comment: пока что никак... я учусь(((